# iPad remote management, but not on apples DEP

Tags: ipad, mobile-device-management

I have a dilemma. I work for a decentralized organization with independent business units.  We’re now starting to centralize the support of IT. 
I have a few companies who bought their own iPads from like Best Buy, amazon and the Apple Store. I had read that you cannot enter consumer purchased iPads into the DEP program.
I have 20 iPads I want to manage and maintain, but it also seems like an Apple ID is a MUST to do literally anything. I read somewhere that an Apple ID has a max limit of 10 devices.
The other problem is when I add a new iPad it sends alerts to ALL the other iPads, which could interrupt or scare a user in a different location.

My question is, how best can I manage and maintain 20+ iPads? I’m currently using InTune, but features a limited without Apples DEP and still requires an AppleID to install any apps.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [What's new in DEP from WWDC17](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/304/). All devices can now be enrolled into DEP regardless of purchase source. Apple Configurator will allow you to provision any device for DEP however these device will be put into a 30 day trial period where the device will display a warning on the lock screen and can be un enrolled at any time.

Comment: That’s useful info. I’m glad that we can now enroll any iOS device. However, we have an entirely Windows 10 ecosystem, I can’t run configurator, and it’ll be really hard asking them to shell out ~1100 for a MacBook or something.

Comment: If I solved your issue could you mark my answer? Thanks!

Comment: sorry, don’t know if you saw my edit, but do you have any suggestions for a Windows based solution?

Comment: Sorry, there's nothing out there yet. Get a used laptop or an old Mac mini. It only needs to be used for configurator however you need to be sure that it can run Sierra.